# $\int \sqrt{25-x^2}x^2\,dx$ with cos-substitution

Tags: proof-verification, indefinite-integrals

I have tried this integral with cos substitution, but I don't understand why it's wrong. So could you please tell me which step is wrong? Here are my steps:
$$
x=5\cos\theta\\
dx=-5\sin\theta\,d\theta\\
$$
therefore
\begin{align}
&(1) = \int \sqrt{25-25\cos^2θ} \, 25\cos^{2}\theta \, (-5\sin\theta) \, d\theta\\
&(2) = -5^4\int \sin^{2}\theta \, \cos^{2}\theta\, d\theta \\
&(\sin 2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta \implies \sin^22\theta=4\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta)\\
&(3) =\frac{-5^4}{4}\int\sin^{2}2\theta\,d\theta\\
&(\sin^2\theta=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2\theta) \implies \sin^22\theta=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos4\theta)\\
&(4) =\frac{-5^4}{8}\int (1-\cos4\theta)\,d\theta\\
&(5) = \frac{-5^4}{8} \left(\theta-\frac{1}{4}\sin4\theta\right) + C \\
&(\sin4\theta=2\sin2\theta\cos2\theta=4\sin\theta\cos\theta(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta))\\
&(6)=\frac{-5^4}{8}(\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)) + C\\
&(\cos\theta=\frac{x}{5} \implies \sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt{25-x^2}}{5})\\
&(7)= \frac{-5^4}{8}\left(\arccos\frac{x}{5}-\frac{\sqrt{25-x^2}}{5}\cdot\frac{x}{5}\cdot\frac{25-2x^2}{5^2}\right) + C\\
&(8)=\frac{-5^4}{8}\left(\arccos\frac{x}{5}-\frac{x\sqrt{25-x^2}}{25}\cdot\frac{25-2x^2}{25}\right) + C\\
\end{align}

Comment: Latex tip: \sin x looks better than sin x. See: $\sin x$ vs $sin x$

Comment: So are you comparing your answer with the author's answer? What if the author used $x=5{\ sint}$?

Comment: When I use the sin-substitution, I get the correct answer when trying to calculate the area. When I use the cos-substitution, the answer is wrong when I calculate the area. I use the antiderivative of desmos/wolframalpha to compare the areas.

Comment: How do you change the corresponding upper - lower boundaries for the cosine sub?

Comment: It seems that in step 2 you  forgot a $\sin \theta$ factor.

Comment: @Emilio: I didn't right? Sqrt (25-25cos^2x) = 5sinx

Comment: @imranfat I use the same upper and lower boundaries for the cos sub and the sin sub, like 0 to 1.

Comment: @Stallmp: sorry !! My mistake ....:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all looks fine, except for a little mistake here in line (7):
$$\frac{-5^4}{8}\left(\arccos\frac{x}{5}-\frac{\sqrt{25-x^2}}{5}\cdot\frac{x}{5}\cdot\frac{\color{red}{25-2x^2}}{5^2}\right)+C,$$
where your sign is flipped. Instead that fraction must be
$$\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt{25-x^2}}{5}\right)^2=\frac{x^2}{25}-\frac{25-x^2}{25}=\frac{2x^2-25}{25}.$$
As far as I can tell, this is the only mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see the mistake. It's correct.

Comment: Wonderful......